# How to Read New Tab location.href.match? using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show alert when the new tab open is match on the URL I want..

I came up with this code..

```
<button class="button" id="open-newtab"
onclick="return ouvre('https://www.facebook.com/');">Open</button>

<script>
function ouvre(fichier) {
ff = window.open(fichier, "popup", "width=600px,height=300px,left=50%,top=50%");
    if (ff.location.href.match(/https:\/\/www.facebook.com/)) {
     alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
} 

}
</script>
```

when I removed the ff on ff.location.href.match it will read the current url of the window not the new tab..

Is it possible to read the location.href of the new tab?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you need this? You open a tab then want to check if it redirects elsewhere?

Comment: I want to call function if the users already on particular link I specified.. alert function is only a example.

Answer (score 3):

As long as the opened window is on the same domain as the parent page you can access the window's url.

But if you want to open a different domain or as soon the user navigates to a different domain you won't be able query it any more.

Comment: but I'm still able to close the new tab using javascript function.. I named the new tab as ff..

Comment: Yes but that's not a possible threat to the user's privacy. Whereas if you open a window and he starts browsing in it and you could keep track of it it would be a big problem.